# Is this the correct equation for derivative of a matrix w.r.t. a matrix?

Tags: matrices, matrix-calculus, tensors

I've been trying to figure out how to do derivatives on tensors (interpreted as multi-dimensional arrays), but the only resources I've found require a lot of development of differential geometry, so I'm not sure I understand it correctly, hence this question.

Write the matrix multiplication $C=AB$ in tensor notation (Einstein notation/Ricci notation?) as $C^i{}_j = A^i{}_kB^k{}_j$, where these are real-valued matrices. Now write the derivative $\frac {\partial C(A,B)}{\partial A}$ as $$\frac {\partial C^i{}_j}{\partial A^p{}_q}=\delta^i{}_p B^q{}_j.$$ Is this correct?

Comment: You have ${ \partial C(A) \over \partial A}(H) = HB$.

Comment: @copper.hat, yes I just derived that. That is correct right?

Comment: I guess you mean $\frac {\partial C^i{}_j}{\partial A^p{}_q}=\delta^i{}_p B^q{}_j.$

Comment: @LorenzoPompili, oops yeah, typo

Comment: Yes, your formula looks correct. By the way, my preference is to compute directional derivatives instead of partial derivatives. So given a function (which can be matrix-valued) $F(A)$ and  a matrix $A'$, it is easy to compute $$F'(A)A' = \left.\frac{d}{dt}\right|_{t=0}F(A+tA').$$ In your example, $F(A) = AB$ and therefore, $F(A+tA') = (A+tA')B = AB + tA'B$. Therefore, $F'(A)A' = B.  For most purposes, the directional derivative is easier to work with than partial derivatives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$
\def\a{\alpha}\def\b{\beta}\def\g{\gamma}\def\t{\theta}
\def\l{\lambda}\def\s{\sigma}\def\e{\varepsilon}
\def\o{{\tt1}}\def\p{\partial}
\def\A{{\cal A}}\def\B{{\cal B}}\def\C{{\cal C}}
\def\E{{\cal E}}\def\F{{\cal F}}\def\G{{\cal G}}
\def\L{\left}\def\R{\right}\def\LR#1{\L(#1\R)}
\def\trace#1{\operatorname{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
$Define the single and double contraction products between tensors as
$$\eqalign{
\F &= \A\cdot\B ​\quad&\implies\quad
​&F_{ij\ell ps}&=\sum_{k=\o}^n \A_{ij\c{k}}\B_{\c{k}\ell ps} \\
\G &= \A:\B     \quad&\implies\quad
&\G_{i\ell ps}&=\sum_{j=\o}^m\sum_{k=\o}^n \A_{i\c{jk}}\B_{\c{jk}\ell ps} \\
}$$
Now consider a fourth-order tensor whose components (in terms of Kronecker delta symbols) are
$$\E_{ijk\ell} = \delta_{ik}\delta_{j\ell}$$
This tensor is the *identity* with respect to the double contraction product. Further, it can be used to rearrange ordinary matrix products, i.e.
$$\eqalign{
&A = \E:A = A:\E \\
&A\cdot B\cdot C = \LR{A\cdot\E\cdot C^T}:B \\
}$$
Applying these ideas to the product in question yields
$$\eqalign{
C &= A\cdot B \\
dC &= dA\cdot B = \LR{\E\cdot B^T}:dA \\
\grad{C}{A} &= \E\cdot B^T \\
}$$
In component form, this becomes
$$\eqalign{
\grad{C_{ij}}{A_{k\ell}}
 = \sum_{p=\o}^n \E_{ijk\c{p}} B_{\c{p}\ell}^T 
 = \sum_{p=\o}^n \delta_{ik}\delta_{j\c{p}} B_{\ell\c{p}} 
 = \delta_{ik} B_{\ell{j}} \\\\
}$$

---

Note that if you are working in a flat space (which is the case for most engineering and business uses of multidimensional arrays), there is no need to distinguish between covariant/contravariant components.

Therefore you can use a simplified notation wherein all indices are written as subscripts. And the Einstein convention applies to any repeated subscript, e.g.
$$
A_{ij}B_{jk}
 \quad\implies\quad
\sum_{j=\o}^n A_{i\c{j}}B_{\c{j}k}
$$

Comment: "there is no need to distinguish between covariant/contravariant components". Isn't the problem with this that we then cannot distinguish between the array $C_{ijk}$ whose components are $A_{ij} \cdot B_{jk}$ and the array $C_{ik}$ whose components are $\sum_j A_{ij}B_{jk}$

Comment: No! You would write the equation either as
$C_{ijk}=A_{ip}\Gamma_{pjs}B_{sk}$
where the middle quantity is a Christoffel-like _symbol_ 
$$
\Gamma_{pjs} = \begin{cases}
1\quad{\rm if}\; p=j=s \\
0\quad{\rm otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
or you'd simply note that the summation convention
is being suspended, e.g.
$$C_{ijk}=A_{ij}B_{jk}\qquad\big({\rm no\;summation}\big)$$
Even in full index notation, the following would raise eyebrows
$$C^{ik}_j=A^i_jB^k_j$$
Although common in Matrix Analysis, elementwise/Hadamard products
are rare in Tensor Analysis.

Comment: Thanks! There must be a more elegant way to write it than $A_{ip}\Gamma_{pjs}B_{sk}$, without explicitly saying "no summation". Actually I guess that you can distinguish between the two simply by writing $C_{ij}=A_{ij}B_{jk}$ if you want to sum them and $C_{ijk}=A_{ij}B_{jk}$ if you don't, since it is unambiguous (though this would still mean that $A_{ij}B_{jk}$ is not an unambiguously defined operation on arrays. You're essentially "type-casting" array multiplication).